# Why built-in functions don't work with events?

Tags: javascript

Why do built in functions not work with Javascript events?

```
document.getElementById('test').onchange = alert("testing");
```

This doesn't work, and fires immediately.

Rather I have to wrap the built-in function inside a function for it to work:

```
document.getElementById('test').onchange = function() { alert("testing"); }
```

Why is this?

Comment: How would the browser know to assign a reference or to call it?

Comment: I don't understand. The function is built-in, isn't it?

Comment: The first you're assigning the result of calling `alert()`.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is passing a function handle vs calling the function.

When you do alert(), you are calling the function, not passing it (technically you pass the result of the function).

In the second case, you are not calling the function, but defining a new function and returning it.